# A textbook solution for a monitoring html page

Tags: javascript, html, monitoring

As a back-end guy, I'm not up to date with GUI libraries and techniques.
I'm well aware of the HTML, CSS & JavaScript trinity and use it occasionally for trivial cases.

What I want to build is an html page with a static structure that monitors a server.
The page contains some fields, tables and trivial controls.
It should update the fields (mainly the tables) whenever data on the server changes.
This means the server has to push the data through an open connection and the JavaScript should parse and display it.

Obviously this can be done manually, but I guess that in this day and age there are solutions that attack such scenarios with just a few lines of code.

What I'm looking for are recommendations for a JavaScript library that can make such a monitoring screen a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a Comet library/solution. I suggest searching for other related questions on SO. I see there is some useful information out there.

I found that there is a [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Comet) and also Dojo has a [project](http://cometd.org/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with [WEBSOCKETS](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/) the downside is that you may need special configuration on server side since this technology is relatively new (introduced with html5) and is implemented just in the newest web browsers.

[This](http://kaazing.me/) is a very good example using websockets the data is updated as it changes in the server side.